# Getting ERR with trying to use GitHub project

Tags: node.js, github

Trying to do this project but hit a brick wall when running this line of code on my Raspberry Pi.

```
npm install https://github.com/stimularity/NaturalNodeLamp.git
```

[image: OUTput]

Comment: `No git binary found in $PATH` - your install is either missing or in the wrong location...

Comment: Thanks that fixed that but now I am greeted with another message:                        
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git submodule update -q --init --recursive
npm ERR! fatal: failed to stat '/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-5f67b4c4': Permission denied
npm ERR!

Comment: `Permission denied`... check your permissions or run as someone who has the correct permissions

Comment: Hello and thank you for your assistanec with this. When you say check your permissions, is on the folder or in the Github directory?

npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git submodule update -q --init --recursive
npm ERR! fatal: failed to stat '/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-8b41f63a': Permission denied
npm ERR!

Answer (score 0):

The error message really says it all - you either don't have `git` installed, or you do and it's not in your `$PATH`. Make sure it's installed and appears correctly in `$PATH`, and you should be good to go.

`apt istall git` should take care of both.